# GCM Chat app - How to know when one user disconnected?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

**The app**

So I'm developing a chat app using GCM. The app works as follow: In a list of users, I can choose with which one I want to talk. Then a request is sent to this user and he has to accept it in order to start the chat. It's like the first user opens a chat room and wait for the other o join in. Im doing all this communication using special flags through GCM messages. Note that a user only exchanges messages inside a "chat room". There's no notification for him if he is outside a chat room.

**The problem**

When a user leaves the chat room I make him send (through onDestroy()) a message through GCM to tell the other user that he is disconecting and therefore the other user won't be able to send him messages anymore. But what if this first user leaves the chat room without calling onDestroy()? (Like closing the app, the app crashes, internet goes down, etc...)

**Solution so far**

When the user sends or receives a message  I update his `last_seen` attribute on my database so I can know more or less if he is still online. So I have a cron job on my server checking from x to x seconds if the users of an active conversation are online and closing it if one of them are not. Note that the proccess of updating the user last_seen attribute is really heavy since I have to make an HttpRequest everytime I receive a GCM message (when sending I already have to make an HTTPRequest, so its not a big problem) and that's why I don't like this solution...

**Question**

Any ideas on how to know if the user is not there anymore?

Thanks in advance, any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You could perfectly use the onStop() method of your chat room activity:

> Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user, because another activity has been resumed and is covering this one. This may happen either because a new activity is being started, an existing one is being brought in front of this one, or this one is being destroyed.
>   Followed by either onRestart() if this activity is coming back to interact with the user, or onDestroy() if this activity is going away.

Set the status as online as long as that event doesn't trigger, if it does, send the last_seen parameter and assume he is no longer in the chat room.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Areks, but it seems that onStop() will be called even if the app is minimized, right? If that's the case then its not a good solution since the user should be able to minimize the chat. And also this doesn't solve the problem of internet going down hmm